# stack 3 div one after the other with position absolute with condition that they shouldn't be allowed to override each other

Tags: html, css

This is my html code.
I want header separated with content and content should be separated with header and footer with each having position equal to absolute and stacked one below the other

```
<body>
    <div id="header" class="div">
    </div>
    <div id="content" class="div">
    </div>
    <div id="footer" class="div">
    </div>
</body>
```

css code

```
.div {position: absolute}
#header{top:0;left:0;right:0}
#footer{bottom:0;left:0;right:0}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to specify **top** in the css of the **content** div, whose value should be equal to the header's height when you are using absolute positioning. One more thing, you may even achieve your purpose with more simple ways by using relative positioning. But as per your approach right now, this could be done.

Here is a working [example](http://jsbin.com/wololimexa/edit?html,css,output).

These are the changes in the css code:

```
.div {
  position: absolute;
  border:solid 1px #000;    /*added this just to visualize things clearly.*/
}
#header{
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  height:50px;  /*specified some random height to the header.*/
}

/* specified css rules for the content div */

#content{
  top:50px;     /*this should be equal to or more than header's height.*/
  left:0;       
  right:0;
}

#footer{
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  height:50px;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hm. I dunno if I really understand your question.

why are you positioning everything absolutely? it takes elements out of normal flow.

for instance if you just use your html:

```
<body>
    <div id="header" class="div">
    </div>
    <div id="content" class="div">
    </div>
    <div id="footer" class="div">
    </div>
</body>
```

And some simple CSS **without** absolute positioning:

```
#header {width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;}


#content {width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: blue;}

#footer  {width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: yellow;}
```

You get three divs stacked on each other. if you want to remove the margins / padding :

```
* {margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "stacked one below the other".
Perhaps you are referring to z-index (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)? In that case, use something like this:

```
.div {
  position: absolute;
}
#header{
  z-index: 3; /* uppermost */
}
#content{
  z-index: 2;  /* in between */
}
#footer{
  z-index: 1;  /* lowest */
}
```

Or are you referring to vertical position? – in which case https://stackoverflow.com/a/33030721/5412860 answer would work.

Though https://stackoverflow.com/a/33030747/5412860 makes more sense...